# bool side = coinFlip == 1 ? true : false;

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I'm currently attempting to solve [the Coinflip challenge](https://ethernaut.zeppelin.solutions/level/0xd340de695bbc39e72df800dfde78a20d2ed94035) by Ethernaut and I have trouble understanding the following line of code (after ==):

```
bool side = coinFlip == 1 ? true : false;
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the ternary operator: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/miscellaneous.html?highlight=ternary

So in your example if `coinFlip` is equal to 1, `side` will be true, otherwise false.

Answer (score 2):

The `bool` variable `side` is being assigned to the result of a ternary operator check.

It's listed in the [miscellaneous section](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/miscellaneous.html) of the docs, and is basically the equivalent of

```
if (coinFlip == 1){ 
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```